# get data hierarchical table

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to make solution this problem when i have table hierarchical in this desaign:
Table Parent

[image]

And i want to join in this table :
Table Category

[image]

Then i want to join table category to table parent.
and then i want the result is new table parent?

Comment: What query have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean by `and then i want the result is new table parent?`?

Comment: can you please give e demo of your final result?

Answer (score 0):

Dont understatd your description of prodblem.
its my example for  table hierarchical

```
WITH p(id, parent, [path]) AS (
        SELECT id
              ,ParentId
              ,CAST(CONCAT('/', id, '/') AS VARCHAR(MAX))
        FROM dbo.table
        WHERE ParentId IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT pp.id
              ,pp.ParentId
              ,CAST(CONCAT(p.[path], pp.id, '/') AS VARCHAR(MAX))
        FROM dbo.table pp
            JOIN p ON p.id = pp.ParentId
    )
    SELECT id, ([path])  AS [path]
    FROM p
    ORDER BY parent, id
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 9);
```